# From where to start such a question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

> 13 equal charges, q , are placed at the corners of a 13 sided regular polygon. What is the force on a test charge Q at the centre?

I couldn't figure out from where to start solving it. It would be very messy to do vector addition of 13 forces. So I think, there must be some trick behind it? Can you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force on a test charge placed at the center of a 13-sided regular polygon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101962/)

Comment: A suggestion: if the title of your question conveys enough information about the question itself  SE software engine starts to suggest you some related questions and sometimes you may find that the answer to your own question is already available. So, it is much better to use specific and focused  than generic titles.

Comment: Please consider writing descriptive question titles with appropriate punctuation, grammar, and formatting. See this meta post: [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413). There's an actual exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the vertices to be the roots of $x^{13}-1$.  The sum of those roots is minus the coefficient of $x^{12}$, which is zero.

Comment: Nice answer. But I think we have here simple geometry valid for any n-polygon : https://imgur.com/a/IqPGgT6. See my answer there : [Force on a test charge placed at the center of a 13-sided regular polygon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101962/force-on-a-test-charge-placed-at-the-center-of-a-13-sided-regular-polygon/454254#454254).

Comment: @Frobenius:  yes, you're right---no regularity needed.  Nice picture.

Comment: I think regularity is needed. I want to say regular n-polygon not restricted to n=13.

Comment: @Frobenius:   Right, of course regularity is needed.  (Otherwise the claim would be that any finite list of complex numbers adds to zero.)   I no longer remember what I was intending to type when I typed this.